# Best way to get a source file list into a Makefile

Tags: c++, file-io, makefile, configure

I would like to separate out my list of source files into their own file (source.list), so that I don't keep having to update the Makefile each time I add something.

source.list looks like:

```
a_file.cpp
another_file.cpp
...
xyz_file.cpp
```

with each file on a newline.

How can I get that list into a Makefile as a space-delimited list?

A configure bash script can be used if necessary. I know awk can be used for this, but I'd prefer to avoid it, if at all possible

Comment: Why are you writing your Makefile by hand? Are build system generators out of the question?

Comment: A configure script can be used, but other than that, nothing

Answer (score 4):

```
SOURCE_LIST := $(shell cat source.list)
```

Answer (score 0):

In gmake use `$(wildcard *.cpp)`

You can use other functions that operate on lists to filter out some source files if needed.

Comment: How will Make know which file names to filter out?

Comment: @Beta: I do not generally recommend using globbing to create the list of sources, but it was kind of asked for (or at least not having to edit the Makefile). If it is possible I would not want to add another file. $(filter-out $(excluded_sources),$(wildcard *.cpp)) will filter out not wanted sources. If the majority of sources shall be added it is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to put the sources into a separate file, you can simply have one or more variables, depending on the number of targets you need to compile all translation units into object files:

```
SOURCE_OBJ1 = src1.cpp depends1 depends2 ...
SOURCE_OBJ2 = src2.cpp depends1 depends2 ...
....
```

save it to sources.list and include it before the actual target definitions in the Makefile:

```
include sources.list
 .PHONY: all
 all: executable

 executable: obj1.o obj2.o
    g++ -o executable obj1.o obj2.o

 src1.o: $(SOURCE_OBJ1)
 src2.o: $(SOURCE_OBJ2)
```

**EDIT**: I generalized the approach for multiple targets with one or more dependencies except for the source file itself. At some point, you will need to get to the Makefile itself again, for instance when you add a new source file that will need to be compiled. What you *can* do in the separated list alone is switching the actual source file and/or alter the target's dependencies without touching the Makefile.

This is all well and good, except for the fact that it is horrible and doesn't scale. Please use a build system generator like CMake or you're not going to have fun when your project grows.

**EDIT2**: Added the phony target that's to be expected for *all*.

**EDIT3**: Please note: the above expects that you replace src1 and so on with actual source file names like *main*. Otherwise make will not deduce the appropriate g++ command line and possible add header files mentioned as dependencies to the list of sources files. The result is an unusable object file.

As an alternative, you can specify both a variable for sources and dependencies and then specify how to invoke the compiler yourself:

```
# sources.list
SOURCES_OBJ1 = src1 src2 src3 # only source files here
DEPENDS_OBJ1 = $(SOURCES_OBJ1) dep1 dep2 dep3 # dependencies might include different file types

# ....

# Makefile
# all the other stuff here
obj1.o: $(DEPENDS_OBJ1) # can now be names however you see fit
        g++ -c $(SOURCES_OBJ1) -o obj1.o # handle compiler invocation manually
```

Note that obj1.o can now have any name that you want to choose and is *not* a PHONY target. Also note that any source file used is also part of the list of the target's dependencies - only the sources, however, are passed to g++ to be compiled.